# Microsoft Graph API unable to update Excel file

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have an Excel file (`.xlsx`), which when I have it already in my OneDrive, I can use a REST command like this, to modify it:

`/v1.0/me/drive/root:/SpreadSheetName.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/content_stats/tables('RawStats')/Rows`

When I modify my code to first upload the file to OneDrive (rather than using the file that is already there), and I use the REST API, I get the error:

> Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'tables'.

I have searched the web for this message, and cannot find anything related to what I am doing. The REST call for modifying the file which was just uploaded is nearly identical, although I do reference the file by `ID` instead, as that is what is returned by the upload API.  This is the URL I use to modify the file which was just uploaded.

`/v1.0/me/drive/items:/<RealExcelSpreadsheetID>:/workbook/worksheets/content_stats/tables('RawStats')/Rows`

Both are doing a `POST`.  Exact same file, only difference is it is being uploaded first, rather than already being in OneDrive. The file was definitely uploaded correctly, as when I go through the OneDrive web interface I do find it and can view it online.  This is a business account.

It was uploaded as MIME type:  `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

It uses these scopes delegated via OAuth2:

- `User.Read`
- `User.ReadWrite`
- `Files.Read`
- `Files.ReadWrite`
- `Files.ReadWrite.All`
- `Sites.ReadWrite.All`

Using Node.js and JavaScript, although that should't matter.

Here is the code used to upload the file:

```js
function copyTemplateInOneDrive(res, queryParam, officeAccessToken, callback) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var excelExt = ".xlsx";
    var excelSpreadsheetFilenameStart = "stats";

    var uploadUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/" +
        excelSpreadsheetFilename + dateNowFull() + excelExt + ":/content";
    var xlsxMimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    fs.readFile(excelSpreadsheetTemplateFilename, function read(error, fileContent) {
        var request = require('request');
        var options = {
            url: uploadUrl,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + officeAccessToken,
                'Content-Type': xlsxMimeType,
            },
            body: fileContent
        };
        request.put(options, function (error, response, body) {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);
            if ('id' in result) {
                console.log("Successfully uploaded template file to OneDrive");
                res.write("Successfully uploaded template file to OneDrive");

                var excelSpreadsheetID = result.id;
                excelSpreadsheetUrl = result.webUrl;
            } else {
                console.log("ERROR: unable to upload template file to OneDrive " + body);
                res.write("Error: unable to upload template file to OneDrive" + body);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, res, queryParam, officeAccessToken, excelSpreadsheetID);
        });
    });
}
```

It uses the async module from node.js (which makes use of callback).  It also saves the ID returned, and later passes it into the call to the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using that triggers this error? There isn't a lot to go on here.

Comment: Hi Marc!  It is the second call to modify the table, as listed above: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items:/<RealExcelSpreadsheetID>:/workbook/worksheets/content_stats/tables('RawStats')/Rows".  Do you want the JavaScript too?  I don't think the JS is bad, being it works with the file when it is already in OneDrive.

Comment: Also, please note you edited out the full URL for the first command, and it lost the "https://graph.microsoft.com/"  although it was kept in for the second command.

Comment: Typically the `graph.microsoft.com` bit is dropped since it can be assumed and shorter strings are a little easier to read in SO. I missed the second call. As for the call, the JS would be helpful. Your calls are almost identical so there is clearly something amiss prior to making the call itself.

Comment: Most likely the issue is with either the uploading of the file or the `ID` you get once the upload is complete.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I added sample upload code.  You can see where it saves the ID for later, where it is used in the call :v1.0/me/drive/items:/" + excelSpreadsheetID + ":/workbook/worksheets/sheetName_stats/tables('RawStats')/Rows";

Comment: Marc: How do I tell if the ID I get back is bad?  The file seems to be uploaded just fine.

Comment: STATUS: When I change the call to the Excel REST API to refer to the filename rather than ID, it updates the spreadsheet properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is the URL you're calling with the `id` is using syntax expecting the file path (i.e. `folder\filename.ext`) rather than the `id`. This is why switching to the file name started working for you.

There are two ways to address a file stored in OneDrive:

1. `drive/items/{item-id}`
2. `/drive/root:/path/to/file` (note the `:`)

You correctly switched your URI from `drive/root` to `drive/items` but by leaving the `:` in place you are telling OneDrive to address the file by it's path rather than it's `id`. In other words, it's looking for a file named `"{some-id}"`.

For addressing a file by it's path, your URL is correct:

```
/drive/root:/{file-path}:/workbook/worksheets/content_stats/tables('RawStats')/Rows
```

For addressing a file by it's `id` however, you need to drop the `:`:

```
/drive/items/{file-id}/workbook/worksheets/content_stats/tables('RawStats')/Rows
```

You can read about how files are addressed in the documentation for [DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem).

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Maybe you can pass on that there could have been a better error message then "Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'tables'." when it was merely an issue that the file could not be opened.